# Elastic Search mappings for spaces and hyphens

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a search index for products and some of the products have a format like so:

```
product1-mk1
product1-mk2
product1-mk3
product2-mk1
...
```

Elastic Search can obviously match very well if someone is searching using the exact phase `product1-mk1` but if a user uses a space instead of a hyphen `product1 mk1` the search results seem wild and the 'product-mk1' is found but it's quite far down in the results.

Is there something I can do in my mappings to account for this? My mappings look like so:

```
        'mappings' => [
            'products' => [
                'name' => [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'include_in_all' => true,
                    'search_analyzer' => 'standard'
                ],
```

My index settings are like so:

```
        'settings' => [
            'analysis' => [
                'filter' => [
                    'ngram_filter' => [
                        "type" => "edge_ngram",
                        "min_gram" => 2,
                        "max_gram" => 6
                    ]
                ],
                'analyzer' => [
                    'ngram_analyzer' => [
                        "type" => "custom",
                        "tokenizer" => "word_split",
                        "filter" => [
                            "lowercase",
                            "ngram_filter"
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'tokenizer' => [
                    'word_split' => [
                        'type' => 'ngram',
                        'min_gram' => 2,
                        'max_gram' => 6,
                        'token_chars' => [
                            'letter',
                            'digit',
                            'punctuation',
                            'symbol'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
```

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated, I assume I'm missing the correct terminology to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.keyword` field if using dynamic mapping for your index or create a keyword field and than use the bool query with should clause on `text` and `keyword` to get the expected results.

Working example using dynamic mapping which creates a `.keyword` field for each text field.

**Index sample docs**

```
{
  "product" : "product1-mk1"
}
{
  "product" : "product1-mk2"
}
{
  "product" : "product1-mk3"
}
```

**Search query with spaces**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "product": "product1 mk1" 
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "product.keyword": "product1 mk1" 
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search results, you can notice first result has ~10X better score**

```
hits": [
      {
        "_index": "hyphen",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.1143606,
        "_source": {
          "product": "product1-mk1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "hyphen",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.13353139,
        "_source": {
          "product": "product1-mk2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "hyphen",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.13353139,
        "_source": {
          "product": "product1-mk3"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

i have faced this recently,
you need to have a custom analyzer, custom char filter mapper, and a custom search analyzer:

```
 "analyzer": {
      "ngram_index_analyzer": {
        "tokenizer": "keyword",
        "type": "custom",
        "char_filter": [
          "ngram_mappings_char_filter"
        ],
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "trim",
          "ngram_filter"
        ]
      },
      "ngram_search_analyzer": {
        "tokenizer": "keyword",
        "char_filter": [
          "ngram_mappings_char_filter"
        ],
        "filter": [
          "trim"
        ]
      }
    },
    "char_filter": {
      "ngram_mappings_char_filter": {
        "type": "mapping",
        "mappings" : ["-=>_"]
      }
    },
    "filter": {
       "ngram_filter": {
       "type": "ngram",
       "min_gram": 1,
       "max_gram": 10
      }
    }
```

for the spaces you can add one more char filter mapping